# JQuery selector bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

The following is a copy of the Watch Expression in my Chrome debug.  It has consumed the past four days of my time.  So even though I believe that I have found the problem, to me, this should not be so.  Can some please explain?

```
$(morphContainer).find('#morph'): e.fn.e.init[1]
$('#morph'): e.fn.e.init[0]
morph.id: "morph"
$(morph): e.fn.e.init[1]
$('#'+morph.id): e.fn.e.init[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is, that even if there is only one element you can find by the selector, jquery put it into an array.

I solved the problem by putting $(selector).find(something) into a var and by knowing there could only be one element by searching for something, temp_obj[0] is the pure element.

```
var temp_obj = $(selector).find(something);
array.push(temp_obj[0]);
```